# eBay API CompleteSaleRequest in delphi doesn't save ShipmentTrackingDetails

Tags: delphi, ebay-api

I'm trying to save `ShipmentTrackingDetails` (`ShippingCarrierUsed` and `ShipmentTrackingNumber`) when calling the `CompleteSaleRequest` eBay API function. As far as I can see all the things I'm doing are according to the eBay API specifications, the call returns a success but when I retrieve the order the tracking details are not saved. My function looks like this:

```
function CompleteSale(OrderID: String; var ErrMsg: String): Boolean;
var
  req: CompleteSaleRequest;
  service: eBayAPIInterface;
  res: CompleteSaleResponse;
begin
  Result := False;
  service := GeteBayAPIInterface(nil, 'CompleteSale');

  req := CompleteSaleRequest.Create;
  req.OrderID := OrderID;
  req.Shipment := ShipmentType.Create;
  req.Shipment.SetShipmentTrackingDetailsLength(1);
  req.Shipment.ShipmentTrackingDetails[0] := ShipmentTrackingDetailsType.Create;
  ShipmentTrackingDetailsType(req.Shipment.ShipmentTrackingDetails[0]).ShippingCarrierUsed := [some custom text];
  ShipmentTrackingDetailsType(req.Shipment.ShipmentTrackingDetails[0]).ShipmentTrackingNumber := [some customer tracking number];
  req.Shipped := True;

  try
    try
      InitRequest(req);
      Screen.Cursor := crHourGlass;
      res := service.CompleteSale(req);
      Screen.Cursor := crDefault;
      Result := True;
    except
      on E: Exception do
        ErrMsg := E.Message;
    end;
  finally
    req.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before anything else, try to check xml generated by Your request and returned by Ebay api. To achieve this, put tXMLDocument on the form, then use 
OnBeforeExecute and OnAfterExecute events of THTTPRIO:

```
procedure TForm1.HTTPRIO1BeforeExecute(const MethodName: string;
SOAPRequest: TStream);
begin
XML1.LoadFromStream(SOAPRequest);
XML1.SaveToFile('Somefile.xml');
...
```

This way You would control Your input xml and eventually change code. 
Basically if You can see ShipmentTrackingNumber and ShipmentCarrieUsed in Your xml, the call should be successfull, however it takes sometimes up to few hours since Ebay actually "refreshes" data on their servers (according to my experience)

If You are interested, there is complete working production solution, unfortunatelly it's C++ Builder:

```
  String    CallName="CompleteSale";
  int SiteId=Ebay->SiteId; //77
  String Version=Ebay->Version;
  String AppId=Ebay->AppId;
  String DevId=Ebay->DevId;
  String CertId=Ebay->CertId;
  String SiteUrl=Ebay->SiteUrl;
  String AuthToken=Ebay->AuthToken;
  String CarrierUsed=Ebay->CarrierUsed;
  String Link=UnicodeString(SiteUrl)+CallName+'&'+"&siteid="+SiteId+'&'+"&appid="+
  AppId+'&'+"&version="+Version+'&'+"&routing=default";

  while(!FDQWorker->Eof) {
  String OrderLineItemId=FDQWorker->FieldByName("OrderLineItemID")->AsString;

CompleteSaleRequest * CS = new CompleteSaleRequest;
CompleteSaleResponse * CSResp = new CompleteSaleResponse;
RequesterCredentials * HDR = new RequesterCredentials;
CallName="CompleteSale";
String PUrl =  Link;
 EbayCall = GeteBayAPIInterface(false,PUrl,HTP1);
 HDR->eBayAuthToken=AuthToken;
 UserIdPasswordType *Cred = new UserIdPasswordType();
 HDR->Credentials  =  Cred;
 HDR->Credentials->AppId=AppId;
 HDR->Credentials->DevId=DevId;
 HDR->Credentials->AuthCert=CertId;
 _di_ISOAPHeaders headers = EbayCall;
 HTP1->SOAPHeaders->Send(HDR);
 HTP1->SOAPHeaders->SetOwnsSentHeaders(True);
 CS->Version=Version;
 CS->OrderLineItemID=OrderLineItemId;
 CS->Shipped=true;
 CS->WarningLevel=WarningLevelCodeType::High;
 ShipmentType * Shipment = new ShipmentType;
 CS->Shipment = Shipment;

 Array_Of_ShipmentTrackingDetailsType ShipmentD;

 ShipmentD.Length=PNumbers->Count; //Multiple Parcels Stringlist

 for (int i = 0; i < ShipmentD.Length; i++) {
  ShipmentTrackingDetailsType * ShipmentT = new ShipmentTrackingDetailsType;
  ShipmentT->ShipmentTrackingNumber=PNumbers->Strings[i];
  ShipmentT->ShippingCarrierUsed=CarrierUsed;
 ShipmentD[i]=ShipmentT;
 }


 CS->Shipment->ShipmentTrackingDetails=ShipmentD;

  CSResp = EbayCall->CompleteSale(CS);
...
}
```

Best Regards

Comment: Thanks for the help! I did manage to find out from the XML that the tracking information wasn't sent. Now I made some changes and the tracking information is in the XML. I don't get the information back when I call the GetOrders function but if I try to send the tracking details again I get an error: "One or more tracking number(s) in the request already exists either for a different buyer or for a different seller." So the tracking details should be there but I do not manage to call them back.

Comment: It says that You've allready used those Tracking numbers, so make sure You use unique numbers for each call.